# Set Word = GetObject(, "Word.Application") works in one sub, but not in other sub in same document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have two codes that create and/or open a Word document from Excel, both contain similar coding including the syntax

Set Word = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

In one sub the document opens perfectly fine and in the other sub I get a runtime error 429 on the above syntax, but only when Word is not open. When Word is open, the function is working just fine.

**Part of the code of working sub**

```
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveSheet.Range("zz_templates").Column).Activate

Range("zz_preventloop").Value = "x"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim DocType As String
If Range("zz_officeversion").Value = "previous to 2007" Then
DocType = ".doc"
Else
DocType = ".docx"
End If

Dim filename As String
filename = Range("zz_envelope_documents").Value + "/" + Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveSheet.Range("zz_locations_doc").Column).Value + "/"
filename = filename + Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveSheet.Range("zz_eDMSname").Column).Value + DocType
      
If Len(filename) < 256 Then
'check the document type
    If Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveSheet.Range("zz_doctype_doc").Column).Value = ".url" Then ''Opening the .url shortcut
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Range("zz_envelope_templates").Value + "/" + ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveSheet.Range("zz_locations_temp").Column).Value + "/" _
        + ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveSheet.Range("zz_hidden_eDMStemp").Column).Value + ".url", NewWindow:=True
    Else
        If Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveSheet.Range("zz_doctype_doc").Column).Value = ".docx" Then
            Application.Calculate
            On Error Resume Next
            Set Word = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
            If Word Is Nothing Then
                Set Word = CreateObject("Word.Application")
            End If

 Rest of sub
```

**Part of code of non-working sub**

```
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveSheet.Range("zz_templates").Column).Activate

Range("zz_preventloop").Value = "x"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      
Dim DocType As String
If Range("zz_officeversion").Value = "previous to 2007" Then
DocType = ".doc"
Else
DocType = ".docx"
End If
    
'check the document type
If Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveSheet.Range("zz_doctype_template").Column).Value = ".url" Then 
''Opening the .url shortcut
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Range("zz_envelope_templates").Value + "/" + ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveSheet.Range("zz_locations_temp").Column).Value + "/" _
    + ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveSheet.Range("zz_hidden_eDMStemp").Column).Value + ".url", NewWindow:=True
Else
    If Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveSheet.Range("zz_doctype_template").Column).Value = ".docx" Then
        Set Word = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
        If Word Is Nothing Then
            Set Word = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        End If

Rest of sub
```

What am I overlooking in the second function that it is not working when Word is not open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problematic one is not identic with the working one:

Your code is missing `On Error Resume Next`.

It should be:

```
On Error Resume Next
Set Word = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Word Is Nothing Then
     Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0 'good to clear the error and let the code raising an error if the case
     Set Word = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

The logic of the above code is:

1. It tries finding the Word open session and create the Word object, if such a session exists.
2. If such a session does not exist, it would raise an error, but `On Error Resume Next` overpass the error.
3. If the Word object could not be created from the existing session, being `Nothing`, a new session is created.

Comment: @Joyce: Glad I could help! But we here, when somebody answer our question, tick the code left side check box. in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue, will now that the code/suggestion works...