# Why VBA command documents.open doesn't works on first run?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, office-automation

I am trying to open a word .docm via a string with Documents.Open. It works after the second run of the script. In the first run the document simply doesn't open up, and the script doesn't load the doc file. Any thoughts or tips?

```
Sub gerarproposta()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Dim objWord As Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document
    
    'banco de dados
    Dim xl As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlw As Excel.Workbook
    
    'Variável texto
    Dim Tex As String
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set basedados = Sheets("Base de Dados")
    Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    objWord.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
    objWord.Visible = True
    
    'xl.Visible = True
    
    
    'Word - proposta modelo
    Tex = """" & basedados.Range("B30") & "\" & basedados.Range("B31") & """"
    'Abre o arquivo do Word
    Set wdDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(Tex)
    .
    .
    .

End Sub
```

- Already tried to change the TEX variable to a String manually
- Every run after the first one works normally

Comment: If you remove `On Error Resume Next` do you get an error? Is a Word startet before you run the macro?

Comment: If I remove On Error, VBA returns a error `cannot create activex component`. The word is closed, even if the word is opened the script doesn't work.

Comment: Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64589173/17172829) how to access word from a other application

Comment: Thanks, that solved all the problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following statement for retrieving the Word `Application` instance can be used if Word is already launched:

```
Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
```

Instead, you could an early binding like you did in case of Excel:

```
Set objWord = New Word.Application
```

Read more about early and late binding technology in the [Early and Late Binding (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/early-late-binding/) article.

Answer (score 1):

The commentary of @Shrotter solved my problem. I changed the code:

```
Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
```

To:

```
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If objWord Is Nothing Then
        Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
```

I tried to get the object from a non-existent Word session.

Comment: Why do you mix early and late binding in the code?

Comment: This is not my code, i'm just solving some issues on it. I prefer early bindings.